# Why doesn't jQuery form .submit() call enclosed function?

Tags: jquery, forms, submit

I am trying to call a named function on form submit. Here is the code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  showPartnerSettings = function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var $dialogForm = $("<div />")
    .attr("id", "partner-settings-form")
    .append($loading.clone())
    .load(envPath + "/partner/settings?partnerid="+e.data.partnerId, null, function(){ $("#partner-settings-form").css("display", "block"); })
    .dialog({
      title: "Partner Settings",
      modal: false, 
      resizable: false,
      width: 580, //CPB 04.11.13
      position:['middle',130],
      "close" : function(){ 
        var dialogid=$(this).parent("div").attr("id");
        $("#Tabs ul li."+dialogid).remove();
        $(this).remove();
        $("#alertmod").remove();
        //$link.removeClass('preventclick');
      },
    })        
    .dialog("open")
    .css("display", "block");

    return false;
  };

$("#partner-settings-form").submit(function(event) { return showPartnerSettings(event); });
```

When I set a breakpoint on showPartnerSettings() it does not break there after the .submit() function executes. Why?

EDIT:

Here's the HTML Jasen requested:

```
<div id="partner-settings-form" style="display: block; width: auto; min-height: 66.6875px; height: auto;" class="ui-dialog-content ui-widget-content" scrolltop="0" scrollleft="0">         
<article class="sign_in form-dialog clearfix">
      <div class="bg-form-dlg">
        <div class="col_100 clearfix">
<h2>UPS Shipping Information</h2>
<form enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded" class="sign_in_form sign_up_form" action="" method="post"><div class="zend_form">
<div class="shippingdetails"><fieldset id="fieldset-account">
<div id="key-label" class="formlabel"><label for="key" class="required">Access Key: *</label></div>
<div id="key-element" class="formcontent">
<input type="text" name="key" id="key" value="CCA574143AD81C1A "></div>
<div id="id-label" class="formlabel"><label for="id" class="required">User ID: *</label></div>
<div id="id-element" class="formcontent">
<input type="text" name="id" id="id" value="argoworks"></div>
<div id="password-label" class="formlabel"><label for="password" class="required">Password: *</label></div>
<div id="password-element" class="formcontent">
<input type="text" name="password" id="password" value="Ubond007gun"></div>
<div id="account_number-label" class="formlabel"><label for="account_number" class="required">Account Number: *</label></div>
<div id="account_number-element" class="formcontent">
<input type="text" name="account_number" id="account_number" value="8X6124"></div>
<div id="address1-label" class="formlabel"><label for="address1" class="required">Address1: *</label></div>
<div id="address1-element" class="formcontent">
<input type="text" name="address1" id="address1" value="112.5 South La Brea Ave."></div>
<div id="address2-label" class="formlabel"><label for="address2" class="optional">Address2:</label></div>
<div id="address2-element" class="formcontent">
<input type="text" name="address2" id="address2" value=""></div>
<div id="phone-label" class="formlabel"><label for="phone" class="required">Phone: *</label></div>
<div id="phone-element" class="formcontent">
<input type="text" name="phone" id="phone" value="2147483647"></div>
<div id="city-label" class="formlabel"><label for="city" class="required">City: *</label></div>
<div id="city-element" class="formcontent">
<input type="text" name="city" id="city" value="Los Angeles"></div>
<div id="state-label" class="formlabel"><label for="state" class="required">State (code): *</label></div>
<div id="state-element" class="formcontent">
<input type="text" name="state" id="state" value="CA"></div>
<div id="country-label" class="formlabel"><label for="country" class="optional">Country:</label></div>
<div id="country-element" class="formcontent" style="">
<select name="country" id="country" class="dlg-select">
    <option value="US" label="UNITED STATES" selected="selected">UNITED STATES</option>
    <option>...etc...</option>
</select></div>
<div id="postal-label" class="formlabel"><label for="postal" class="required">Postal Code: *</label></div>
<div id="postal-element" class="formcontent">
<input type="text" name="postal" id="postal" value="90036"></div></fieldset></div>
<div>
<p><label id="configship-label">&nbsp;</label>
<input type="submit" name="configship" id="configship" value="Save Information"></p></div></div></form></div>
</div>
</article>

    UPS342hi</div>
```

I found the problem with your help. I wasn't attaching the .submit() to a form element. Now I'm trying to fix that, and I'm running into a different problem. Do you know how I can access the POSTed form data from JS? I need access to a hidden field named "partnerId" in the form. Is form data included in event.data? Thanks for your continued help.

Comment: If I put a `console.log` as the first line of your `showPartnerSettings` function, I see that it is being called on form submit. Where are you breaking and what kind of errors are you seeing in the browser's debug console?

Comment: @Jasen, I put the breakpoint on e.preventDefault(). There are no errors. It just ignores the contents of the anonymous function handler passed to .submit().

Comment: Do you have html markup for `partner-settings-form` before the dialog is created?

Comment: If somebody answered your original question, then please accept their answer.   If you have another question, then please post a new question.  Please do not change your OP each time your question is answered.

Comment: @BarbaraCaryBarnhill sorry, I meant does your form have html markup defined before the dialog call. Is it generated after the page is initially loaded?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are creating your `partner-settings-form` in an entirely dynamic manner (html markup did not exists when the page was first loaded) then your `submit` event registration would not have been bound to the form.

You'll need to wire this up slightly differently:

```
$("body").on("submit", "#partner-settings-form", showPartnerSettings);
```

This example is using `body`, ideally you'll choose an element selector that's static at load time as close to your dialog as possible.

Note:

1. If you're not doing anything else on submit then you can get rid of the anonymous function.
2. It seems odd you're building `partner-settings-form` on the submit event for `partner-settings-form`.

Comment: Thanks for helping me solve my problem. I fixed it slightly differently from your suggestion. Now I have a different issue. Maybe you could help with that too? Here's the link to my new question:

Comment: Sorry, here's the link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16532250/how-can-i-access-form-post-data-from-jquery-submit-event-object

Comment: OK, here it is with markdown: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16532250/how-can-i-access-form-post-data-from-jquery-submit-event-object)[/link] I hope this works.

Comment: Regarding your second point, I am rebuilding the form based on the submit action in response to form validation errors. I need to redisplay the form with the errors.